# MVC How to add Client side validation to Radio Buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a radio button that only shows up when certain values are chosen above so in some cases the radio button wont have a checked value so I cant put a required data annotation to the model. Is there any way to make a radio button required only when the question shows up.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd need this at all. Once selected, user can't deselect a radio button in any way.

Comment: You need conditional validation

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `error` div class, and check if no radio check append your error message as

```
$('#Next').click(function(){
            if ($("[name='myoptions']:checked").length == 0){
                $('.error').text("Radio is required.");
                return false;
            }
 });
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Next').click(function(){
            if ($("[name='myoptions']:checked").length == 0){
                $('.error').text("Radio is required.");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.radio{
margin-right: 10px;
}

.error{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="red">Radio 1<br /> 
 <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="green">Radio 2</div>                                                    
<div class='error'></div>    

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" id="Next"/>

<script>
   
</script>
```